# How to resolve enhanced-for-loop error in JRE older version?

Tags: java

I am trying to upload and retrieving resume.while retrieving resume it shows error Change project compliance and JRE to 5.0... How can i resolve it without updating my jdk & jre version?

This is my code....

```
import java.io.File;
 public class ReadFilesFromFolder
  {
   public static File folder = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 5.5\\webapps\\workspace\\uploadfile\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\filedir\\");
    static String temp = "";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        System.out.println("Reading files under the folder "+ folder.getAbsolutePath());
        listFilesForFolder(folder); 
    } 
    public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder)
    { 
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles())
        {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) 
            {
                // System.out.println("Reading files under the folder "+folder.getAbsolutePath());
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } 
            else
            {
                if (fileEntry.isFile()) 
                { 
                    temp = fileEntry.getName();
                    if ((temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, temp.length()).toLowerCase()).equals("txt"))
                        System.out.println("File= " + folder.getAbsolutePath()+ "\\" + fileEntry.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Whoa, you need to add a lot more details. *What* gives you the error? The Oracle Java compiler? Your IDE? (What is your IDE?). I doubt you get it at runtime ("while retrieving resume") because it looks like a compiler error. What *is* the version of the JDK/JRE that you have? If it is below 5.0 you are a *serious* number of years out of date.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting the error `Change project compliance and JRE to 5.0` you need to change your compiler settings by these steps

```
Window->preferences->Java->Compiler-> and change the compiler compliance level to 1.5
```

hope this helps!

Good luck!